# How to make predictions on a logistic regression model with a separate df for train and test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I am working on a logistic regression model. I started out with two separate CSV files, one for training data and one for testing data. I created two separate data frames, one for each data set. I am able to fit and train the model just fine but am getting an error when I try to make predictions using the test data.

I am not sure if I am setting my y_train variable properly or if there is another issue going on. I get the following error messages when I run the prediction.

Here is the setup and code for the model"

```
#Setting x and y values
X_train = clean_df_train[['account_length','total_day_charge','total_eve_charge', 'total_night_charge', 
            'number_customer_service_calls']]
y_train = clean_df_train['churn']

X_test = clean_df_test[['account_length','total_day_charge','total_eve_charge', 'total_night_charge', 
            'number_customer_service_calls']]
y_test = clean_df_test['churn']
```

```
#Fitting / Training the Logistic Regression Model
logreg = LogisticRegression()
logreg.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

```
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='warn',
          n_jobs=None, penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='warn',
          tol=0.0001, verbose=0, warm_start=False)
```

```
#Make Predictions with Logit Model
predictions = logreg.predict(X_test)

#Measure Performance of the model
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report

#Measure performance of the model
classification_report(y_test, predictions)
```

```
  1522     """
   1523 
-> 1524     y_type, y_true, y_pred = _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
   1525 
   1526     labels_given = True

E:\Users\davidwool\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\metrics\classification.py in _check_targets(y_true, y_pred)
     79     if len(y_type) > 1:
     80         raise ValueError("Classification metrics can't handle a mix of {0} "
---> 81                          "and {1} targets".format(type_true, type_pred))
     82 
     83     # We can't have more than one value on y_type => The set is no more needed

ValueError: Classification metrics can't handle a mix of continuous and binary targets
```

Here is the head of the data that I am working with. The churn column is completely blank as it is what I am trying to predict.

```
clean_df_test.head()

    account_length  total_day_charge    total_eve_charge    total_night_charge  number_customer_service_calls   churn
0               74             31.91               13.89                 8.82                               0     NaN
1               57             30.06               16.58                 9.61                               0     NaN
2              111             36.43               17.72                 8.21                               1     NaN
3               77             42.81               17.48                12.38                               2     NaN
4               36             47.84               17.19                 8.42                               2     NaN
```

Here are the dtypes as well.

```
clean_df_test.dtypes
account_length                     int64
total_day_charge                 float64
total_eve_charge                 float64
total_night_charge               float64
number_customer_service_calls      int64
churn                            float64
dtype: object
```

The main problem is that I am used to using sklearn's `train_test_split()` function on one dataset where as here I have 2 separate datasets so I am not sure what to set my y-test to be.

Comment: The error discribes there is inconsistent types in either y_test or the predictions. Try printing the types of y_test and predictions as well as the shapes of these.

Comment: Please update your question to include a sample of your `y_test` and `predictions`.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have updated the post with some additional information.

Comment: Your y_test should be your labels for your test set if you're generating a classification_report. It seems like they're all NaNs in your data.

Comment: So the labels are either 1 (for yes) or 0, how would I display that? Sorry I know that's probably a basic question but I haven't done logit without using sklearn train, test, split before.

Comment: Basically your clean_df_test is not correct. Your "churn" column is empty. With this mistake the model can't predict. How did you obtain this dataframe?

Comment: @AlexSerraMarrugat I was sent this dataset, the original test dataset did not have a "churn" column so I added that in because I thought it would be necessary in order to make a prediction.

Comment: My goal is to add a column named "churn" to the test data set with the predictions of either "yes" or "no".

Answer (score 2):

The problem becomes evident by looking at `clean_df_test.head()`. I can see there are null values in the column `churn`.

As a consequence, `y_test` contains null values, and by passing it as `y_true` to `classification_report()`, you are making the function compare nulls against integers, which is raising an error.

To solve this, try dropping the rows where `churn` is `NaN` and run the rest of your code as before.

```py
# Drop records where `churn` is NaN
clean_df_test.dropna(axis=0, subset=['churn'], inplace=True)

# Carry on as before
X_test = clean_df_test[['account_length','total_day_charge','total_eve_charge', 'total_night_charge', 
            'number_customer_service_calls']]
y_test = clean_df_test['churn']
```

Another way of spotting this issue is to look at the data types of `clean_df_test`. From the output, `churn`'s type is `float`, which should not be the case if it was filled exclusively with ones and zeros!